# Elastic Beanstalk Deployment Does not work for deploying changes

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I had deployed a java application using Elastic Beanstalk. I had to make some changes to the application. But when I try to redeploy the changes using elastic beanstalk again, my changes arent applied. 
If i deploy the same application to a new environment, I see the changes.

Am i missing something while redeploying? I am using the eclipse AWS plugin to deploy.

Comment: Did you check the logs? Were there any anomalies in the event streams?